# Data processing - how to input a pandas column that contains numbers and numpy arrays

Tags: xgboost, preprocessing, word2vec

I have a pandas df that contains numbers and strings. I use word2vec to convert all the strings into embeddings. The problem now is that these embeddings are all numpy arrays. So now my pandas df becomes a mixture of numbers and numpy arrays. How do I feed this into an XGBoost model (since an XGBoost model needs data in the form of a list of numbers and not a list of numbers and lists)? Are there any efficient methods of doing so?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply convert the elements in these numpy arrays to separate columns in your dataframe?